# How can I get the user to type multiple inputs?

Tags: python, input

I want to write a simple code to find the area of a triangle using the formula: A=(1/2)b(h) where b is the base and h is the hieght. How can I ask the user to enter 2 inputs, b and h?

Comment: Still answered the question, go ahead and look at it.  I even covered how to convert variables into floats (as that is probably what you want).  If you could do me a huge favor and mark it was solution and upvote it that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.x you can take input using the input() function.  It will print a string and then take input from the user.  I also added a small line of code showing how to convert that into a float and then do the mathematics.

```
input1 = input("What would you like your base of the triangle to be? ")
input2 = input("What would you like your height of the triangle to be? ")
print ("Your result " + str(.5 * float(input1) * float(input2)))
```

In Python 2.x

```
input1 = raw_input("What would you like your base of the triangle to be? ")
input2 = raw_input("What would you like your height of the triangle to be? ")
print ("Your result " + str(.5 * float(input1) * float(input2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.x:

```
base = input('Enter base: ')
height = input('Enter height: ')
```

Please note, `base` and `height` is string here. So, convert it to `int` or `float` before computation.

In Python 2.x:

```
base = raw_input('Enter base: ')
height = raw_input('Enter height: ')
```